What size wire nut for joining #8 and #10 wire?
I am installing an air conditioning surge protector at the outside unit. In the disconnect box I need to remove aluminum #8 and combine with surge load of 10ga copper stranded and the pigtail going up to disconnect. The pigtails are both 10ga stranded wire.
What wire nut for aluminum/copper and the 3 wires?

Welcome, Tom. Please take the [tour] so you know how to properly respond to answers. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

It isn't combined sizing of 5ga. Wire nuts have specific combinations of sizes permitted.
Ideal is one of the largest manufacturers of wire nuts. From the Ideal catalog:
Twister 65 Purple includes combinations:

1 #10 Al solid w/1 or 2 #10 Cu solid
1 #10 Al w/1 or 2 #12 Cu
2 #10 Al solid w/1 #12 Cu
1 #10 Al w/1 or 2 #14 Cu
2 #10 Al solid w/1 #14 Cu
2 #12 Al solid w/1 #10 Cu
1 #12 Al solid w/1 or 2 #10 Cu
1 #12 Al stranded w/1 or 2 #10 Cu solid
1 #12 Al w/1 or 2 #12 Cu
2 #12 Al solid w/1 #12 Cu
1 #12 Al w/1 or 2 #14 Cu
2 #12 Al solid w/1 #14 Cu
1 #10 Al w/1 or 2 #18 Cu
2 #10 Al solid w/1 #18 Cu
1 #12 Al w/1 or 2 #16 Cu
2 #12 Al solid w/1 #16 Cu
1 #10 Al w/1 or 2 #16 Cu
2 #10 Al solid w/1 #16 Cu
1 #12 Al w/1 or 2 #18 Cu
2 #12 Al solid w/1 #18 Cu

Note that none of those include #8 Al. Which means Ideal is not an option, and I suspect most other brands are not either. AlumiConn 3-port connectors only list up to #10 as well.
Which all leaves open the question: How are your existing #8 Al and #10 Cu connected now?

Break out the wallet crowbar and go shopping for Polaris connectors seems like the most likely compliant solution. Many will be too large, but it appears the IPL4-3 or IPL1/0-3 do extend down to include both 8 & 10AWG in their range of operations. Or use a two-port IT4 or IT2 to convert the 8 AWG aluminum to copper before joining the 3 wires with all being copper.

My electrician used something like https://buy.wesco.ca/Wiring-Connectors/Connectors-and-Lugs-Mechanical/Multi-Use-Cable-Terminals/Terminal-Lugs/ABB-INSTALLATION-PRODUCTS/Mechanical-Terminal-Aluminum-Tin-Plated-1-2-inch-Hex-Socket-CU-AL/ADR60-21/p/78378661033-2 and wrapped it in electrical tape?  The polaris thing looks like a better solution.
